# how can I use Do loop to plot function of two variables on single plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Friends, I have function COs[x^{2}+2 n] + n, how can I plot this function on single plot with x,0,10 and n,1,9. What I need, is x-range on x-axis and function value as y-axis. It will like a filled density plot. Thanks in anticipations.

Comment: Is there some reason using a `Do` loop is required?

Answer (score 0):

Not a filled density plot...

```
Show[Table[
  Plot[Cos[x^2 + 2 n] + n, {x, 0, 10}],
  {n, 1, 9}], PlotRange -> All]
```